# How to get the data of an object which is an implementation of an inteface

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, interface, polymorphism

```
@Data
    public class Vehicle {
        public VehicleType type;
        public VehicleInfo info;
    }
    
    public enum BehicleType {
        BIKE,
        CAR;
    }
    
    @Data
    public interface info {
        
    }
    
    @Data
    publcu class carInfo implements info {
        String carName = "audi";
    }
    
    @Data
    public class bikeInfo implements bike {
        String bikeName = "BMW";
    }
    
     getVehicleName(Vehicle vehicle)
     {
         if (vehicle.getType() == BIKE) {
             return vehicle.getInfo().getBikeName();   // Here we need the name based on type
         }
         else {
             return vehicle.getInfo().getCarName();
         }
     }
```

I have two classes whose are implementations of an interface. How can get the name of vehicles based on type. Like I need to get `vehicle.getInfo().getBikeName();` if type is bike, otherwise `vehicle.getInfo().getCarName();` ? Is it even possible with this design pattern ?

Comment: You could by checking the result of `getClass()` and then cast the result of `vehicle.getInfo()`, for example, but wouldn't it be better if `info` was called `Info` instead and had a method `getName` that `carInfo` and `bikeInfo` should implement to return `carName` and `bikeName` respectively?

Comment: Is this a real requirement that both your implementation have a different parameter name : carName and bikeName ?  if not, replace it by just name

Comment: Yeah. They have to be different

Comment: You've tagged your question with oop and polymorphism. I would recommend you have a look more in detail on oo principles and design because the code you have above, and what you ask for, doesn't really make sense. E.g. with the above implementation, any time you add a new vehicle type, you would need to update your "getVehicleName" method, which isn't good design.

Answer (score 0):

If you use constants in the info name, you can only use Enum for this. When you want to add a new vehicle, then you will add one entry to the Enum and it will work:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum VehicleType {

    BIKE("Audi"),
    CAR ("BMW");

    private final String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This will be enough for the method:

```
public String getVehicleName(Vehicle vehicle){
        return vehicle.type.getName();
    }
```

In your example, the ENUM value does not guarantee that the Vehicle Type matches.
In this case, you need to check the instance type

```
public String getVehicleName(Vehicle vehicle){
        if (vehicle.info instanceof CarInfo) {
            return ((CarInfo) vehicle.info).getCarName();
        }
        if (vehicle.info instanceof BikeInfo){
            return ((BikeInfo) vehicle.info).getBikeName();
        }
        return ...
    }
```

But as said above this is not a good design